# Matlab GUI, how to go back from subplot to a single plot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, subplot

I am having a simple GUI with two pushbuttons. One of them is plotting a single plot, one is plotting two subplots. However, once I push the subplot option, I cannot go back to the single plot. I am getting an error:

> error using axes, invalid object handle

Please see below my very simple example:

```
function plot_push1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
load('test.mat')
axes(handles.axes1)
cla(handles.axes1,'reset')
plot(x,x.^(n+1));

function push_plot2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
load('test.mat')
axes(handles.axes1)
cla(handles.axes1,'reset')
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(x,x.^(0));
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(x,x);
```

Comment: I've not designed a GUI before, but might `subplot(1,1,1)` work?

Comment: I have tried that, didn't work :(

Comment: You can try [`clf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clf.html).

Comment: I have tried `clf` too, it is clearing the whole interface.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue here is that `subplot` *creates a new `axes` object* (or transforms the current axes). You'll need to take this into consideration when manipulating your `axes` objects.

```
axes(handles.axes1);    

subplot(2,1,1);             % This is still handles.axes1
plot(x, x.^(0))

newax = subplot(2,1,2);     % This is a new axes
plot(x, x);
```

If you want to use a container in GUIDE, I would define a `uipanel` instead of an `axes`. Then all subplots can live within this panel.

```
function plot_push1_callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % Make one plot in the panel
    subplot(1,1,1, 'Parent', handles.panel);

    plot(x, x.^(n+1));

function plot_push2_callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    % Make the first subplot in the panel
    subplot(2,1,1, 'Parent', handles.panel)

    plot(x, x.^0);

    % Make the second subplot in the panel
    subplot(2,1,2, 'Parent', handles.panel)

    plot(x, x)
```

Comment: In Guide I have prepared a dedicated space (axes1) in which I would like to plot different things, depending on the pushbutton pressed. I have tried to put the suggested `delete()` instead of my `cla()` but it also doesn't work. I am a bit lost now, how do you suggest I should arrange these two pushbuttons?

Comment: @Agnieszka A subplot creates two axes. In GUIDE you would want to use a `uipanel` as the container to plot things in NOT an axes.

Comment: @Agnieszka Added an example of how to do that